# Problem adding Js variables in HTML with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<h1>Operadores aritméticos</h1>
<h3>+ Adición (102+103)=</h3><p id="suma1"></p>
<h3>- Substracción</h3><p id="resta1"></p> 
<h3>* Multiplicación</h3><p id="multi1"></p>
<h3>/ División</h3><p id="div1"></p>
<h3>% Módulo</h3><p id="mod1"></p>
<script>
var suma = (102+103);
var resta = (36-20);           
var multiplicación = (27*30);
var división = (900/30);
var módulo = (106%3);
document.getElementById("suma1").innerHTML = suma;
document.getElementById("resta1")innerHTML = resta;
document.getElementById("multi1")innerHTML = multiplicación;
document.getElementById("div1")innerHTML = división;
document.getElementById("mod1")innerHTML = módulo;
</script>
```

Hello guys, I have a problem, im pretty new at this (programming with HTML, Js, etc.).The issue is that when I try to make my Js variables appear on HTML (with document.getElementById), they do not appear. Nevertheless, if erase every document.getElementById except the one containing "suma1", the browser displays me the result of the sum (205), but if I add even one of them, the browser doesn´t display anything. 
I hope I was clear with my problem, it seems very simple but hard to explain.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing some `.`s before `innerHTML`s!

Comment: Open your browser's developer tool. You should see messages about syntax errors. The developer tool is your best friend :) Learn about it and make use of it.

Comment: Adding on to @FelixKling, if you're using Chrome, right click the page and click `Inspect`, all kinds of cool tools are now available for you to analyze your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing anything when you add the statements to populate `resta1`, `multi1`, `div1`, and `mod1` is probably because they all have a syntax error. This is likely causing even the first statement (`suma1`, which is syntactically valid) not to work.

### Valid Statement

The 1 statement that is working is `document.getElementById("suma1").innerHTML = suma;`

### Invalid statements

All the other statements follow this pattern:

`document.getElementById("id")innerHtml = variable;`

**Note that you're missing the `.` between `getElementById("id")` and `innerHtml`.** If you add the missing `.` then it should all work as expected.